# malformed url java selenium while using local picture

Tags: java, selenium, image-uploading

So I'm trying to upload an image using Selenium so that I can test some functionality of a website. I have tried various things and have been unable to get the image to upload.

I've tried attachFile:

```
selenium.attachFile("id=upload_field", "C:\\bacon.jpg");
```

I've tried using the driver as in below code to find the element:

```
WebElement uploadImage = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']"));
uploadImage.sendKeys("C:\\bacon.jpg")
```

I've also tried the find by element with the button ID:

```
WebElement uploadImage = driver.findElement(By.id("upload_button"));
```

I've also tried using the click and upload method but that errors out when I use click and tells me I should be using attachFile. `The website uses a modal window to upload a story.`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Oh, when I use attachFile I get the error:

> com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: Malformed URL:C:\bacon.jpg

Comment: try `file:///C:/bacon.jpg` and see what happen?

Comment: In the sendKeys call?

Comment: I get the error of `Element is not currently not visible and so may not be interacted with`